# Does Oracle hard parse a command again if aliases are changed?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

If I execute a command like this:

```
select a.Id, b.Name from A b, B b where a.Id = b.Id
```

and then a second command like this, changing the aliases:

```
select c.Id, d.Name from A c, B d where c.Id = d.Id
```

There would be two hard parse operations? There is something like a parse cache? If yes, how does it work?

Comment: Of course the second statement needs to be parsed...

Comment: How would a query parsing cache help if query *changes*?

Comment: Ok. I thought there might be a "pre-parse" operation that modifies all aliases to something incremental and verify if there are a entry in cache. We use here a framework that generate aliases kind of randomly and people are saying it hurts performance.

Comment: c and d are just alternate names for your datasets you got from A and B

Comment: Here where I work a DBA said "sure it hurts, because these two commands are different", but maybe Oracle is smart enough to see that these two commands are the "same". I want to verify that with some documentation, but I couldn't find.

Comment: The SQL_ID for a given sql statement is generated from the hash value of the SQL_TEXT. Therefore, if you change the text in the sql statement, it will generate a different SQL_ID, even if logically they are the same statement. A new SQL_ID means a hard parse is required.

Comment: @andrucz: your DBA is right

Comment: I wonder why Oracle does not have a step that ignore irrelevant differences if even in a soft parse, a syntatic and a semantic check are executed (is not just a "if there are a cache entry with this string key, consider it"). Anyway, thank you guys for your help.

Comment: sql_id is computed as md5 checksum and only 8 significant bytes are used from it. See: http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2009/02/22/sql_id-is-just-a-fancy-representation-of-hash-value/. The only transformation before md5 checksum, I'm aware of is newline conversion. CR/LF -> LF. Otherwise comments, aliases or even white spaces can change sql_id.

Comment: "*does not have a step that ignore irrelevant differences*" - because that step would be the parsing step. There is no other way to identify those differences.

Comment: Yes, but that would be a part of soft parse and would avoid a hard parse and performance problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle checks the checksum of your query and reparse the query if the checksum has been changed.

So, yes it will reparse the query. Even if you will add/remove a whitespace, the checksum will change so Oracle will have to reparse it.

Comment: doesn't the configuration of your property CURSOR_SHARING influence this? If you set it to SIMILAR, wouldn't that see the 2 above queries as the "similar" ?

Comment: it applies to values/constants/literals **only**. So if you put another whitespace, rename alias, etc. Oracle will re-parse your query.